# How to get access to the value of variable within a dictionary with modern objective-c syntax

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I'm new to ios programming.

I'm trying to get an access to variables in a dictionary with modern objective-c syntax like the code below.

But, none of these works.

The first line and second line fails when running ios simulator.

The third one cause an error when I press a button on the screen.

```
//NSDictionary *myData = @{@"name":@(nameField.text), @"birthdate":@(birthField.text), @"sex":@(selectedSex)};

//NSDictionary *myData = @{@"name":@nameField.text, @"birthdate":@birthField.text, @"sex":@selectedSex};

NSDictionary *myData = @{@"name":nameField.text, @"birthdate":birthField.text, @"sex":selectedSex};
```

This error message appears when I try the third line above.

```
2013-10-02 09:12:56.160 LifeTimer[18603:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught
exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary
initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[0]'
```

How can I fix this problem?

I think I'm misunderstanding something very basic.

Comment: "attempt to insert nil object" -- I'm guessing at least one of your values is nil.

Comment: The syntax is `@{key:value, key:value...}`.  You only use `@` inside the `{}` for literals (and usually your key values are string literals).

Comment: Oh I see! You are right!!! Thank you very much. I found it one of my values is nil.

Comment: Interesting. I answered the same below. I assume you should count it as a right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can not define dictionaries with nils by using literals syntax. The same was for old ways of defining NSDictionary through methods like initWithObjectsAndKeys:, initWithObjects:forKeys:count: and others. Nils are not allowed till you will not wrap them into an NSNull that confirms NSCopying protocol which is mandatory for both keys and values of NSDictionary.

Comment: It didn't work in a such way always. Literals internally use method initWithObjects:forKeys:count: which didn't allow nils in values or keys, it will throw such exception.

Comment: Odd that you completely reversed your answer.

Comment: Sorry man. Was typing in the hurry and missed "not". I even was confused by your question. Didn't get from beginning that you pointing to my mistype.

Answer (score 0):

`[[myDict objectForKey:@"id"] intValue]` assuming `id` is an `int` if the value is a string you don't even need the last method: `[myDict objectForKey:@"name"]`